# Foundation 6 columns grid classes not being applied

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

I am just trying to get a simple project started using foundation 6.  My very simple html is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Foundation for Sites</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-2 columns">
                <h1>test</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="large-2 columns">
                <h1>test2</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/what-input.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/foundation.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).foundation();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, when testing the website, the column classes are not getting applied and the grid is not working as it should be.  Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're using < foundation 6, you need to be using the XY-grid because the old float grid was deprecated.

Check this out: https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/xy-grid.html

Your html would look something like this using the XY-grid:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Foundation for Sites</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="grid-x">
            <div class="cell large-2">
                <h1>test</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="cell large-2">
                <h1>test2</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/what-input.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/foundation.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).foundation();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add that you can still use the float grid in Foundation 6. If you visit the [download page](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/download/), you can select "Float Grid" under "Grid" in the left column and download that custom build. You do not have to use the XY Grid.

If you do that, your existing grid markup will work.